# BunnyHop Soft Landing

Tags: bmx

I broke my pedal today. I own a bmx. It happened when I landed from an american bunnyhop. Any tips to land softly? (I have even bent the rim.)

Comment: Front or rear wheel? Did you use your legs effectively as suspension? What vertical travel did you achieve by doing it?

Comment: front wheel. I did not do more than 40cm

Comment: if you hopped no more than 40cm and broke a pedal and bent your front rim, there must be some other contributing factor. even the cheapest bike in reasonable condition shouldn't be damaged like that from a 40cm bunny hop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can practice making the bunny hop more of a fluid movement. Imagine a jump without a bike over something quite tall:

- Compress and leap
- Tuck at the apex of the jump
- Extend back down
- Feet land and absorb the landing with legs

Being rigid, stiff or having bad timing with any of that will cause harsher landings with or without a bike.

Trials riders dropping from large heights extend the rear wheel and have that land first with their legs absorbing the landing with the front wheel landing a bit later.

Trying to refine your technique with smaller jumps will help by focusing on the sequence of things to make you and your bike act like a big spring:

- compress
- front wheel up a bit earlier
- followed fluidly by back wheel - tucked
- extend back wheel down first
- compressing legs and letting down the front wheel

Work a bit on smaller bunny hops - maybe up and down a curb - until you can start to feel yourself landing with a bit less force or until you get a sense that you are anticipating the landing.

It was easier for me to yank and jump higher, but it took a while for me to learn how to jump in such a way that I was landing more gracefully and not thrashing my bike, body and wrists. The finesse and feel takes longer but is worth it!

Everything happens in such a short period of time it's a little tough but you'll start to feel what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a modern BMX then the saddle should be super low. If it is not then move it at the very bottom.

BMX bikes are very very stiff (100psi tyres, rigid cromo frame, rock solid wheels) so you need to absorb the imact with your feet and upper body. Landing with the rear wheel first (just slightly) helps trigger the feet at the exactly correct time. Another thing that helps is that when you start descending (from the bunnyhop) you extend your feet in order to give yourself enough room for absorption.

If you don't absorb with your feet then the weakest link will have to deal with the whole impact (knees, pedals, head tube of frame etc).

Keep in mind though that parts do fail. Broken pedals and bent rims is not something unexpectable in the BMX world.

Comment: I feel like there is not enough time to straighten my legs. I usually land with the front(slightly)

Comment: Then your bunnyhop (or drop to flat) is not high enough to require this. Don't worry, this is normal. You can just absorb with your feet going from semi-bent to fully-bent.

Comment: I cant make it higher :S ...

Comment: You can't make it higher right now, but if you practice, you will.

Comment: I have been practising more than 3 months.

Comment: Keep it up. General riding and fitness also helps a lot.